# Is it secure to store validated Form data in Session superglobals in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a quite simple question, which I'm asking because I'm unsure of the answer. I'm building an application where there is a multistep registration form. There are 7 steps and each one is on a different PHP page. I'm also validating the submitted form data once the client goes to the next page.

My questions is:
Is it secure to store all the Validated(only the validated) information in a Session variable and when they've finished with the registration, I'd write those session values into the Database. Is it secure to use sessions for this purpose? If not, how can this method be exploited?

I am also providing the option for people to go back to each step and change the values if they've mistyped something. In this case I would update the Session variables only. Is it safe too?

I'm currently using `session_regenerate_id()` to prevent Session stealing.

So basically will I be safe to store the data in Sessions temporarily, and then insert them to the database? Can a hacker change that Session data in the meantime, so what I'll insert into the DB will not be the same what I've saved into the session?

I hope you understand my question. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Sessions are a server-side storage system. If hackers can write random files on your server, you have bigger problems to care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is secure. Session data is stored on the server side, and cannot be manipulated by the client. The only thing the client holds is a session key, which allows the server to match a client up with the stored session vars for that client. As long as you're validating the information before storing them into `$_SESSION`, you can dump the session variables into the database at the end of the process.

Here is [more information on sessions and security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php). The simple solution to any concerns with session stealing is to just use SSL.

> I am also providing the option for people to go back to each step and change the values if they've mistyped something. In this case I would update the Session variables only. Is it safe too?

You will also be fine with this approach, again as long as you're re-validating the session variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm much more calm now. +1 for the additional resource.

Answer (score 0):

if you protecting session ids for session stealing then go ahead, sessions are safe variables stored in server-side , every client has own session so if you sure to keep safe your session ids then no problem